# matlab plot table - two cell arrays for labels and one vector of doubles

Tags: string, matlab, scatter

I have a 3 column table named 'A' from which I want to plot a heatmap or scatter plot where I can see a colour for the coordinates indicated by the first two columns.   For example, at row 'A91552' and column 's_4_AAGCTA' I want to see a colour corresponding to 0.47619.

Example data:

```
'A91552'    's_4_AAGCTA'    0.476190000000000
'A91554'    's_4_CCTATT'    0.476190000000000
's_4_AAGCTA'    'A91552'    0.476190000000000
's_4_CCTATT'    'A91554'    0.476190000000000
```

Is there a way to do this directly using the strings as indices, or will I need to make a double matrix and change the axis labels on something like imagesc?

Comment: I have not used it myself, but the ["DataMatrix"](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/datamatrix.html) class seems to [overload the "plot"function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/plotdatamatrix.html) to do what you are looking for. I'm sure there are many other ways to achieve what you are after. :)

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

I just needed to convert my lists of strings to categorical variables:

```
scatter(categorical(A.Var1), categorical(A.Var2), 125, A.Var3, 'filled')
```